# Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/facebook/shimmer/shimmer/null/shimmer-null.pom'. Received status code 401 from server:

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder, shimmer

I am facing  below error while running the expresso test.

**Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/facebook/shimmer/shimmer/null/shimmer-null.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project**

I have tried  disabling offline mode in gradle still its not working. Below is my project gradle configuration

[image]

Anyone know why this error? and how solve it?

Comment: Just to make sure: is this `/null/` in the URL intentional? Is it supposed to be working with it?

Comment: I have not added parameter to URL. Jus added    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0@aar'. in app gradle

Comment: I understand, I'm just saying that maybe check what gets called if you use JDK 8, and see if there's any difference. Seeing it (if it exists) will probably point you in the right direction.